# How to prevent popup from closing when touch keyboard shows?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBox in WPF popup and behavior of closing it when focus is lost works as intended with mouse/keyboard, but if user uses on-sceeen touch keyboard, Windows opens touch keyboard and the popup loses focus and closes.

I have tried to handle this but it made no difference

```
private void Popup_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // additional logic here to check if OSK if following line worked
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

is there a way to preserve popup only if the focus is lost to touch / on screen keyboard?

Edit:
I already know about `StaysOpen` but it should close when user clicks something else, just not OSK

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the PlacementTarget to the parent ItemsControl, then set VerticalOffset and HorizontalOffset properties of the popup to specify it's exact location on the screen and force it to stay open (example below)

```
popup.IsOpen = true;
popup.StaysOpen = true;
```

Comment: I intentionally didn't set StaysOpen because it should close when user clicks something else, but it should stay open for OSK

Comment: You can't control what the win10 keyboard does, or at least I don't know how, since it's something very much external of your program. You can create your own popup keyboard and handle it like you wish and that will work as you want